# Cacti on pgsql in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, psql, cacti

## Description

I have a laravel app, that I am trying to integrate that with **[Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/)** : is a complete network graphing solution designed to harness the power of RRDTool's data storage and graphing functionality.

---

## Steps

I've downloaded it, and place it in my `public/` directory.

Now, when I go to my `http://localhost:8888/cacti/`

---

## I got

**First Try**

> FATAL: Cannot connect to MySQL server on 'localhost'. Please make sure you have specified a valid MySQL database name in 'include/config.php'

---

Then, I opened up 'include/config.php'. Since my goal is to try to connect it to `pgsql` instead of `mysql`, so I here is my current settings

```
$database_type = "pgsql";
$database_default = 'cacti';
$database_hostname = 'localhost';
$database_username = 'postgres';
$database_password = '';
$database_port = '5432';
$database_ssl = false;
```

As soon as I hit **saved**, and refresh the page  `http://localhost:8888/cacti/`

**Second Try**

Now, I got : `The localhost page isn’t working` :(

[image]

---

## Database

I've already created a `cacti` database on my localhost running on port `5432`.

[image]

Comment: Did you create a cacti database in pgsql?

Comment: Yes, I did. See it [here](https://postimg.org/image/c047oeqat/)

Comment: @ihue did you check this ? http://forums.cacti.net/about23300.html

Answer (score 2):

As given in [this site](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Cacti), cacti is designed to work with only MySQL.

> Cacti is written in PHP and supports MySQL only for storing the
>   RRDTool data.

Though, there is this link to setup the cacti with `pgsql` .
[PostgreSQL Host Template](http://forums.cacti.net/about23300.html)

Comment: I wish you or someone can show a nice steps of how to integrate Cacti with psql rather than shot me a link to forum that noone is replying.

Comment: @ihue sorry for that.. but I don't have much knowledege about Cacti.. though I will try implementing and will let u know the results...

Comment: Are you on a Mac ? I am. I try the first step according to your link and I could not find all those stats settings on the Postgres.conf and if u can update your implementation- it will be nice.